# Can't install anything with apt-get. There appears to be an error of unmet depenndencies

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, dpkg, latex

Already tried out the following commands after seeing many answers but none seems to be working:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo dpkg -a --config
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I am pasting few lines of the error that I get when I try to install anything.

```
texlive-luatex : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-math-extra : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-metapost : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-music : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-omega : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-pictures : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-pstricks : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
                    Recommends: texlive-font-utils but it is not going to be installed
                    Recommends: texlive-extra-utils but it is not going to be installed
 texlive-science : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-xetex : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 tipa : Depends: texlive-base-bin
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

The following are the errors I get for the failing commands:
`sudo apt-get -f install`:

```
Preparing to unpack .../texlive-fonts-extra-doc_2018.20180505-1~16.04.york0_all.deb ...
Unpacking texlive-fonts-extra-doc (2018.20180505-1~16.04.york0) over (2015.20160320-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-fonts-extra-doc_2018.20180505-1~16.04.york0_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/mweights/README', which is also in package texlive-latex-extra-doc 2015.20160320-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-fonts-extra-doc_2018.20180505-1~16.04.york0_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I checked and other commands also have the same error.

output for `dpkg -l | grep york`:

```
iU  context                                       2018.04.04.20180416-1~16.04.york0            all          powerful TeX format
ii  libpython3.6-minimal:amd64                    3.6.3-1ubuntu1~16.04.york1                   amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.6)
ii  libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64                     3.6.3-1ubuntu1~16.04.york1                   amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (standard library, version 3.6)
iU  prosper                                       2018.20180505-1~16.04.york0                  all          TeX Live: transitional dummy package
ii  python3-gdbm:amd64                            3.6.3-0ubuntu1~16.04.york0                   amd64        GNU dbm database support for Python 3.x
iU  python3-tk:amd64                              3.6.5-3~16.04.york4                          amd64        Tkinter - Writing Tk applications with Python 3.x
ii  python3.6                                     3.6.3-1ubuntu1~16.04.york1                   amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 3.6)
ii  python3.6-minimal                             3.6.3-1ubuntu1~16.04.york1                   amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.6)
iU  texlive                                       2018.20180505-1~16.04.york0                  all          TeX Live: A decent selection of the TeX Live packages
iU  texlive-fonts-recommended-doc                 2018.20180505-1~16.04.york0                  all          TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-fonts-recommended
iU  texlive-full                                  2018.20180505-1~16.04.york0                  all          TeX Live: metapackage pulling in all components of TeX Live
iU  texlive-htmlxml                               2018.20180505-1~16.04.york0                  all          TeX Live: transitional dummy package
```

Output for `apt-cache policy texlive-fonts-extra-doc`:

```
texlive-fonts-extra-doc:
  Installed: 2015.20160320-1
  Candidate: 2018.20180505-1~16.04.york0
  Version table:
     2018.20180505-1~16.04.york0 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
 *** 2015.20160320-1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Show us the output of the failing commands. Edit your post and add the results, formatted with the `{}` button

Comment: @waltinator I have added the errors but sorry that I could format it the specific way you wanted I think.

Comment: Do you have PPAs added to your system? It seems that you have TeXLive-related PPA from JonathonF. Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep york` and `apt-cache policy texlive-fonts-extra-doc` to the question. Which version of TeXLive do you plan to use - 2015 (from Ubuntu repository) or 2018 (from PPA)?

Comment: @N0rbert added the outputs. Any version would be fine as long as it doesn't affect my normal installations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you do not need exact version of TeXLive I recommend to remove [jonathonf texlive PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/texlive) and install packages from official repository:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:jonathonf/texlive
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. For other users, start from the second command as the first command will give the same error as was given for all installation trials before.